# Getting a Syntax Error: if len(sys.argv) =! 5 no clue why the code is wrong

Tags: python, syntax-error, argv, sys

Hello I'm working on my first python script and I've got a

> Syntax Error: if len(sys.argv) =! 5::

I really have no clue what is causing it. I'm using Python v3.3.3 in Wing IDE 5.0 on a windows box. It's my first script but I do know other programming languages so I don't care if the answer is difficult to understand. It's probably a noobish error.. Does it maybe have something to do with the new syntax?

```
import shodan
import requests
import sys 

SHODAN_API_KEY = "ENTER API KEY IN HERE"
api = shodan.Shodan(SHODAN_API_KEY)
iptotal = ('IP list')
pagenmbr = 1
if __name__ == "__main__":
        if len(sys.argv) =! 5:
                print('Usage: <query> <username> <password> <lastpagenumber')
                sys.exit(0)

                query = sys.argv[1]
                username = sys.argv[2]
                password = sys.argv[3]
                endpage = sys.argv[4]
                iteratePage(pagenmbr)



                def iteratePage(pagenmbr):
                        try:
                               ...

                        except (shodan.APIError, e):
                                print ('Error: %s' % e)  

pagenmbr = pagenmbr + 1

if pagenmbr <= endpage:
        iteratePage(pagenmbr)

print(iptotal)
#Append succeeded items to file
with open("outputsbb.txt", "a") as myfile:
        myfile.write(iptotal)
```

I left out the try commands to save some space. If anybody has had this error before or could help me with this plz reply and help a fellow coder out it's really appreciated

Comment: Use `!=`  not `=!`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You invert the `!` and the `=` in your condition. You wanted to write:

```
if len(sys.argv) != 5:
     #...
```

See [list of Python operators](http://www.python.org/doc//current/library/operator.html#mapping-operators-to-functions)

Answer (score 1):

You want `len(sys.argv) != 5`

- `!=` is "is not equal to"
- `=!` does not exist in the python grammer

Comment: Lol how retarted :D Thanks anyway seems like sleep deprivation can get the best of me.

Comment: @DedicatedDreamer: happens to the best of us. Dream on!